# Partial page update

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a masterpage that contains a widget in which there is navigation. 
The masterpage furthermore contains content placeholders for the child pages that inherits the master page..

However when im switching between the pages attached to the master, it updates the entire page. 
this means that my widget slides back to initial position, and the page scrolls up. This to me seems counter intuitive and unprofessional.

Is there a way in which i can make it only update the content placeholders?

Comment: Look into [AJAX](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: If you are using asp.net mvc then you can use partial view for your scenario.